# Adding/inserting values in pandas dataframe based on 1 or more columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes

```
date       sitename  Auto_name                  AutoCount                         
2012-05-01 chess.com Autobiographer               8
2012-05-05 chess.com Autobiographer               1
2012-05-15 chess.com Autobiographer               3
```

And

```
date       sitename  Stu_name      Student count
2012-05-01 chess.com Student        4
2012-05-02 chess.com Student        2
```

How the output should be

```
date       sitename    Autoname                 AutoCount     Stu_name    Stu_count                     
2012-05-01 chess.com Autobiographer               8            Student       4
2012-05-02 chess.com Autobiographer               0            Student       2
2012-05-05 chess.com Autobiographer               1            Student       0
2012-05-15 chess.com Autobiographer               3            Student       0
```

I want to insert the name and student count from second into first but based on date column.  It doesn't look that difficult, but I am not able to figure out this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eg use the `merge` function (see the docs on merging dataframes: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). Assuming your dataframes are called `df1` and `df2`:

```
In [13]: df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
         date   sitename       Auto_name  AutoCount Stu_name  StudentCount
0  2012-05-01  chess.com  Autobiographer          8  Student             4
1  2012-05-05  chess.com  Autobiographer          1      NaN           NaN
2  2012-05-15  chess.com  Autobiographer          3      NaN           NaN
3  2012-05-02  chess.com             NaN        NaN  Student             2
```

Above it uses the common columns to merge on (in this case `date` and `sitename`), but you can also specify the columns with the `on` keyword (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)).

In a next step you can fill the NaN values as you like. Following your example output, this can be:

```
In [15]: df.fillna({'Auto_name':'Autobiographer', 'AutoCount':0, 'Stu_name':'Student', 'StudentCount':0})
Out[15]: 
         date   sitename       Auto_name  AutoCount Stu_name  StudentCount
0  2012-05-01  chess.com  Autobiographer          8  Student             4
1  2012-05-05  chess.com  Autobiographer          1  Student             0
2  2012-05-15  chess.com  Autobiographer          3  Student             0
3  2012-05-02  chess.com  Autobiographer          0  Student             2
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking on same lines. Does merging on more than one column (date and sitename in this case) take more time than merging on a single column (just date). I am merging very large dataframes. So need t think about the computation time.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you can always test and time it (eg with `%timeit` in ipython).