# Merge rows of a dataframe in pandas based on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
sitename            name        date               count
0  chess.com  Autobiographer  2012-05-01               2
1  chess.com  Autobiographer  2012-05-05               1
2  chess.com  Autobiographer  2012-05-15               1
3  chess.com  Autobiographer  2012-05-01               1
4  chess.com  Autobiographer  2012-05-15               1
5  chess.com  Autobiographer  2012-05-01               1
```

How to merge the rows based on date and sum up the count for the same date. Like in sql

```
select sitename, name, date count(*) from table group by date
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: I used `df = dataframe.groupby('date')` . I  got this error pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f0d2de6f9d0>
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x32bdb90>

Comment: @user3527975: that's not an error.  That's simply what a groupby object looks like when you print it: you want to perform some operation on it (like selecting a column, or performing a sum, etc.)

Comment: @DSM : Thanks. Yes I want to perform a sum based on the date. But I want all the columns to be preserved in the updated dataframe.

Comment: @DSM : I have posted one more question on this site - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901459/adding-inserting-values-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-1-or-more-columns. Haven't got anything on this one. Do you have any idea for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to keep your sitename and name in your dataframe, you can do :

```
df = dataframe.groupby(['date', 'sitename', 'name']).sum()
```

EDIT : See **@DSM**'s comment to reset the indexes and have a non indexed dataframe.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for saving time. I was writing functions and doing an dataframe.apply

Comment: This combines the sitename date and name as one single column. But these have to be separate coulmns. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @user3527975: no, it doesn't. You're probably confusing the index (which in this case is a multiindex) with a column.  You can add `.reset_index()`, or add `as_index=False` to `groupby`, e.g. `groupby(["date", "sitename", "name"], as_index=False).sum()`.

Comment: @DSM : I should have said it combines sitename, date and name and uses it as index. as_index = False does the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = dataframe.groupby('date').sum()
```

Comment: This one just keeps the date and sum in the dataframe. Whereas the structure is desired like in the post

Comment: You can add the columns and then if you want to print the result and keep the headers/columns add this `, header=True, index=True)`